# Security checklist

Tags: php, apache, security

I am looking for a security check list to check it before publishing every site , ie how to secure your server  ,
please share me with your experience , i am hosting my website on private vps , with out any hosting panel

Comment: Doesn't appear to be a programming question. This may be better suited on serverfault.

Comment: securing php , apache , mysql is programming related , isn't ?

Comment: security of apache, mysql and php is related to how they are set up on the server. Security of your PHP code on the other hand is widely broad programming issue, that just can't be addressed with one answer... Search around a little and I am sure there will be plenty of information relating to this (found this literally in 5 seconds http://www.sk89q.com/content/2010/04/phpsec_cheatsheet.pdf)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two parts to your question, one programming related and one not (this is why you have downvotes, as you specificially ask about the second one). First, you need to secure your actual code/application from application-based attacks. Second, you need to secure your server and deployment.

The second question, on how to secure your server, is not programming-related and does not belong on SO. You may try serverfault.com for that.

For the first question, how to properly secure your actual application, this requires a lot of training on secure development methodologies. However, **at the very least** you should be familiar with the OWASP Top Ten list of common web application vulnerabilities and you should specifically make sure that your application is not vulnerable to any of them. This list is available at [the OWASP website](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category%3aOWASP_Top_Ten_Project). Study this list, analyze your application, and deploy mitigations against these problems. In-depth guidance on how to do so is also present within the OWASP webspace - use it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are hosting your sites on VPS or Cloud without a panel then you have to manage the OS layer too. It basically comes down to a few good practices: expose the minimum services especially for administration, using a bastion to access your servers, update regurlarly, subscribe to security news channels, an check SSL settings.

We recently published this article which you might find usefull: https://www.exoscale.ch/syslog/2016/02/12/wet-your-feet-with-security/